He speaks scarcely a word of Russian

He speaks scarcely a word of Russian.

[From an English-Japanese dictionary.]
I don't know what exactly this sentence means. The position of "scarcely" is confusing to me.
Which is "scarcely" modifying, speaks or a?
The adverb "scarcely" is a strange word to me because it has two meanings "only just" and "almost not", but I am assuming that in the sentence, it means "almost not".

"to not speak a word of (language)" is an idiomatic construction, so best not to try and break it into individual words.

Scarcely a word means essentially the same thing as barely a word: he speaks only a very few words (of Russian).
So what scarcely modifies is the noun phrase a word of Russian. It looks like an adverb, and it often is used as an adverb, but here it’s not modifying the verb Another example of such adjectival use is Scarcely anyone is left who remembers that day.  The subject of the sentence is scarcely anyone.
Other such words (that can modify either verbs or nouns) include nearly and almost. They aren’t full-fledged adjectives, because you can’t say things like *The scarcely boy saw the dog. You can, however, say things like The scarcely a dozen people who attended the concert did enjoy it. Here, scarcely modifies the noun phrase a dozen people who attended the concert.

Compare the colloquial

I've been there many a time.

The singular "a time" is modified by many and the result is "often".

He said scarcely a word all evening.

The meaning is that he said  only a few words over the course of the evening. He was taciturn.
That which is "scarce" (as a resource or commodity) is in short supply, hard to find. There is little of it to be had. The adverbial form in this construction also has that idea of "small number" or "little amount".

Hardly a day goes by when I don't think of her.
There's rarely a meal he's late for.

